# bash No space left on device

Tags: ubuntu, bash, disk-space, vps

On VPS when I press tab under my user I get:

```
bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

but it works fine under root, what's happening?

Comment: Which filesystem? With ext2/ext3/ext4 see `tune2fs`'s option `-m`.

Comment: If the error is this clear, you could’ve included the output of `df` right away. ;) Also, the output of `df -i`, please.

Answer (score 3):

As you press tab certain/specific script(s) is/are launched
*(several can be defined, which one that gets launched depends on the command currently typed at the prompt)*.
These scripts often use temporary files in /tmp

The login where you see this has either ran out of space in /tmp (e.g. quota), alternatively has no quota at all, or the script is (erroneously?) attempting to write/handle too large data.

Generally root has more quota or no limits.

```
sudo -i
cd /tmp
du -h | sort -n | less
```

should display what there is in /tmp and the space it occupies.

Also:

```
df -h --output=source,target,ipcent,pcent
Filesystem     Mounted on     IUse%  Use%
...
```

should, in a "normal" situation not have high numbers under the Use%-columns, for either /tmp or tmpfs (which there is, depends on system setup).

Comment: `df -h` should help as well

Comment: Reverted, tmpfs might be in use - /tmp in RAM. Thanks for reminding @Daniel B

Answer (score 0):

Check how your filesystem is formatted. Typical setups I ran into used these settings:

- Format Ext2  (ok, now somewhat dated an probably ext4)
- **Reserved space: 5%**.

The last means that 5% of the space is reserved for uid 0.

If you have a 200GB drive and one single partition, then a regular user can fill it up to 190GB. At that point she will get an filesystem full error.  Df will report 100% in use.

If, at this time, you try this as root you can write up to another 5%. Df will show over 100% full.

Now apply that to your problem. Is a filesystem which is being used over 100% full?

Answer (score 0):

We got bit with this today, and it turned out to be [an issue with the Inodes](http://www.ivankuznetsov.com/2010/02/no-space-left-on-device-running-out-of-inodes.html).

You should run `df -i` to see how many Inodes you're using. If your `IUse%` is at or near `100`, you should find as many small or zero-sized files you can, and delete them all.

You can find the files with (credit to the linked article):

```
for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
```